# Memoir parskip package

Tags: spacing, memoir, paragraphs, parskip

How do I get the same effect as using the `parskip` package when using the `memoir` class.

I want no indents, and spaces between paragraphs. What is the proper way to do this in the `memoir` class?

Answer (score 16):

Memoir explicitly warns against this: (p. 47)

> If you like the idea of eliminating
>   paragraph indentation and using extra
>   inter- paragraph space to indicate
>   where paragraphs start and end,
>   consider how confused your reader will
>   be if the last paragraph on the page
>   ends with a full line; how will the
>   reader know that a new paragraph
>   starts at the top of the following
>   page?

But it also provides methods for doing so:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\nonzeroparskip
```

Or you can set a specific value yourself using

```
\abnormalparskip{<length>}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know memoirs warns against this. Unfortunately it is the format of my thesis. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it.

\usepackage{parskip} does it all nicely when not using memoirs.

Comment: The method here *is* the cleanest with `memoir`.  It effectively does the same thing as loading `parskip`, AFAICT. (And it's only one more line of code!)

Comment: It's actually also a point that indented paragraphs isn't correct typography for all languages.