# Occasional gap between paragraphs, no indent on first para

Tags: memoir, indentation, paragraphs

In LaTeX I'm using `memoir` class. I want to break long passages into logical units with some white inter-paragraph space. `\medskip` etc. indents the first subsequent paragraph - I want it unindented, as paragraphs are when starting a section. Can anyone advise? Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you. EDIT: Actually, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22553/memoir-parskip-package is an even closer duplicate.

Comment: Please indicate whether or not you are the same person who "answered" below. If this is the case, it is possible to merge your accounts across the sites - moderators can also assist with this task.

Comment: I don't consider the two other questions in doncherry's comment to be similar.  They are about getting space between all paragraphs and no indent in any paragraph.  This question is about getting space between two blocks of paragraphs and indenting all paragraphs except the first one in a block.  The newcommand in Werner's answer below works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Using `\noindent` removes the indent (of length `\parindent`) from a single paragraph and requires manual usage at every paragraph. To void the paragraph indent altogether, use

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

in your document preamble, or at the start of your document (after `\begin{document}`).

---

If you're after an automated approach to have some paragraphs not indented after placing a `\medskip`, you should define your own `\medskipnoindent` macro (defined as `\medskip\noindent`) that does exactly that. Here's a minimal example showing this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newcommand{\medskipnoindent}{\medskip\noindent}%
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1] \medskip
\lipsum[2] \medskipnoindent
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The above example has a standard inter-paragraph skip. If you want to remove this, you could use `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}`. Regardless, for any `\parskip` or `\parindent`-related modifications, consider using the [`parskip` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip).

Answer (score 4):

Try starting the paragraph with `\noindent`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make this an answer instead. Try `\fancybreak{}`